# Pdfplumber - Extract a table in pdf without any borders

Tags: python-3.x, tabula-py, pdfplumber

I am trying to extract the table as shown in the image here into a data frame. I tried using tabula-py to extract the code but read_pdf returned me []. Not sure if tabula-py is the right module to use. Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the error. I was using the wrong option. I should have used the stream option instead of the lattice option.

```
df = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_path, stream=True, pages=1, area=(87,72,160 , 200), pandas_options={'header': None})
```

Thanks.